# Print json content from wp site in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, wordpress, get

sorry for the noob question, but I think I am doing something wrong. So the idea is to fetch the json data of a Wordpress post and then print only the text content of the wp post. I am using the following setup:

```
    url = "../wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}"
    user= ""
    password = ""
    credentials = user + ':' + password
    token = base64.b64encode (credentials.encode ())
    header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode ('utf-8')}
    responce = requests.get (url, headers=header, params="title")

    return (responce.text)
```

I need it to be a string to use it within a label, but I am probably doing this wrong, any advice will be highly appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking, but if you want a string, you could try something like this:

```
return (str(responce))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is:

```
url = "../wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}"
```

That is a relative URL, and for `requests` you need an absolute URL. So either provide an absolute URL or you can compute it with the following by providing your current URL, for example:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

current_url = "https://www.example.com/abc/def/x.py"
print(urljoin(current_url, "../wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}"))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.example.com/abc/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{id}
```

Second, `resonce.text` will return a bytes (Python 3). If you want the content returned as a string (unicode), then return `responce.content`. You haven't said exactly *what* your problem is except "you need it as a string", so I assume this is your other problem.

Comment: Thank you! I am using the absolute url, just didn’t want to post it here and it works, the issue is it is printed in json format and I need the content of the wp post in a text format and it needs to be a string not an object as I’ll use it in a Label (I am using the kivy framework) I hope this makes sense I am a newbie so I may not explain myself very well, sorry!

Comment: No, it's not very clear. It is `responce.json()` that returns an *object* by parsing the `JSON` string that is returned (remember: `JSON` is a *string* representation of an object). Otherwise, `responce.text` is a string, which in this case would be `JSON` *string*. You need to specify in your question what the **hoped for value is** versus **what you are getting** and you need to be very precise.

Answer (score 0):

I used :
return str(json.loads(responce.text))
and it worked great ^^